# Git Bash cannot find git directory when git is installed

Tags: macos, git, bash, ssh, capistrano

I'm running `cap deploy` to deploy a site to a server. It deploys just fine, except for this last part:

```
export GIT_RECURSIVE=$([ ! \"`git --version`\" \\< \"git version 1.6.5\" ] && echo --recursive) && git submodule -q update --init $GIT_RECURSIVE && (echo b8ce153ac56e3e79eda1e053b922ac48e775321a > /var/www/alkdfjf/releases/20130822204731/REVISION)
```

If I didn't have `git`,  I have git installed, as it clones just fine. But at this step, I receive an error stating:

```
bash: "git: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: Maybe you could update the question with the actual `capistrano` task code you are trying to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the .git folder those files are in is usually hidden and needs higher privileges. Are you sure you don't need or that you are sudo or whatever the equivalent is on Macs?

Answer (score 2):

Use the full path to `git` in your command, i.e. `/usr/local/bin/git` or what ever it is on your system.

Comment: I am using Capistrano so I cannot specify the full path.

Comment: The question states that you are trying to run the command in `bash`, and `bash` does not find `git` in its `PATH` on whatever system you are running that `export` command on.